# Wordpress css won't change unless I edit cache/combined.css

Tags: css, wordpress

I've made changes to some css but they don't go into effect. I have to edit a file in cache/combined.css. Did wordpress create this file?

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

It is part of a caching system to speed up to Wordpress site to run faster. You probably have a caching plugin enabled and what you would need to do is use the feature of that plugin (if there is one) to clear the cache.

Alternatively, you could just delete that file out of cache and it should re-cache the new file on next page load.

Comment: Adding to this answer: Don't edit the cached css file because it will be deleted once the cache has updated. If you're making a lot of updates to the CSS, turn off the cache plugin and make the changes or work the clearing cache task into your workflow.

Comment: Sound advice @austinthedeveloper thanks for adding that to it.